# same text in two pages but diffrent <a> style

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I have a database where i insert news. These news are displayed in 2 different pages (one of those inside footer) and i want to be able to use different < a> style in those pages.
The text is collected from database in both pages but is treated different as style in footer.
All is well till here but when i have an < a> tag, only one style is applied to that tag...

Is there a way to change the  tag style only in footer but not in the other page?

here is part of the footer code that gets the news from database

```
<table class='noutatitabel'>
<tr>
<td class='faramargini'>
<div class='data'>
<div class='luna'>$Luna</div>
<div class='ziua'>$Ziua</div>
</div>
</td>
<td class='white'>$Mesaj
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
```

In the other page i have replaced the

```
<td class='white'>$Mesaj</td>
```

with

```
<td class='albastru'>$Mesaj<td>
```

i use

```
<a id="link4" href="link">text</a>
```

the css for id link4

```
#link4{color: #fff;}
#link4:visited{color: #fff;}
```

Is there a way to use different styles in those pages?

Comment: Write CSS that only targets links in the footer. If you can show some code, we can help you write the proper CSS.

Comment: there's clearly a css issue here. This question can not be resolved without seeing your code. If you dont upload your code this question will end up getting down voted and closed.

Comment: Can you share your markup so that we can help you with the selector?

Comment: "Knowledge is painful but the lack of knowledge is killing me." damn , how can you disrespect knowledge . I don't think Knowledge is painful at all .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have many experience with CSS right ?

The CSS selector has different ways. Assume that you want to only select a link in  the child element, you can use the next CSS selector

```
td.white a#link4 {
    // your css here
}
```

this one will style only the a with id "link4" which is a child of td class="white" element.

```
td.albastru a#link4 {
    // your css here
}
```

this one will style only the a with id "link4" which is a child of td class="albastru" element.

Comment: Yup... this is it. Just learning CSS... Thank you!